# Visibility timeout for part of consumers

Tags: azure, queue, azure-storage-queues

I'm trying to create a resilient system based on `Azure Storage Queue`.

I have workers in two different Azure Regions that are processing messages from the same queue. I would like to prioritize the worker from the same region as a Queue **before** the worker from the second region will start handling the message.

My idea was to use a *visibility timeout* feature that will vary by worker type. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

> My idea was to use a visibility timeout feature that will vary by
>   worker type. Is it possible?

To the best of my knowledge, it is not possible. A message can only have a single visibility timeout that is set either when a message is sent to the queue or when a worker updates the message by dequeuing it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Maybe there is another alternative to make it work as expected?